# Jumbotron images slider

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

hui guys,
i have my jumbotron and full background image placed in it. I was thinking to myself whether is it possible to make it not only one static image but to make some slides contains of e.g 5 pictures which could slides every hmm 5 sec? Is it possible? How could it implement what i mentioned? My current implementation below:

html:

```
 <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
            </div>
            </div>
```

and css for it:

```
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    background: #000 url('35.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 370px;
}
```

problem with second galery slider after implementing the top one:

```
<!-- Gallery -->
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div class="page-header" id="gallery">
                <h2>Kilka wykonanych projektów.<small> Couple of already realased projects.</small></h2>
            </div>

            <div class="carousel slide" id="screenshot-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="highway.jpg" alt="Text of the image">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Highway heading</h3>
                            <p>This is the caption</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="river.jpg" alt="Text of the image">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>River heading</h3>
                            <p>This is the caption</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="street.jpg" alt="Text of the image">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Street heading</h3>
                            <p>This is the caption</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="painting.jpg" alt="Text of the image">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Painting heading</h3>
                            <p>This is the caption</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- End Carousel inner -->
                <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                </a>
            </div><!-- End Carousel -->

        </section>
    </div>
```

this is how it looks after image is changing:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this bootply code for a demo on how to customize a jumbotron inside a carousel: http://www.bootply.com/61935

The basic gist is to place the jumbotron inside the divs for the container of the carousel, so u have the properties of the jumbotron being cycled as in a carousel.

Comment: ok its working, but when i wanted to use it again more down on the webpage its not working like it would be static. I can click arrows but images are not changing also whole slider is not on all width, whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For a reference with carousel with jumbotron, you can check [my practice page](http://sirjan.com.np/bootstrap/3.html)!. It has readable code if you inspect it.

**whole slider is not on all width** you have put it inside a container div. Just close the container div and reopen it inside the jumbotron (This is optional. You can use it without container too. Or use container-fluid in place of container to cover the full width)